# How to modify error messages in Loopback 4?

Tags: javascript, loopback

Here's a sample error message generated by Loopback for unique item:

```
{
    "error": {
        "statusCode": "422",
        "name": "Error",
        "message": "ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry 's@a.com' for key 'email'",
        "code": "ER_DUP_ENTRY"
    }
}
```

However, I want to modify it as:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "email": [
            "The field email should be unique"
        ]
    }
}
```

Documentation really didn't help me. Can anybody help me on this please?

Answer (score 3):

You can return custom error using `HttpErrors` object from `@loopback/rest`. Please [click here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Controllers.html#handling-errors-in-controllers) for more.

```
throw new HttpErrors.UnprocessableEntity('limit is not a natural number');
```