# How to specify minimum and maximum length for fields in Loopback 4?

Tags: javascript, loopback

I have defined the property in my model as follows:

```
@property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
    min: 2,
    max: 255
})
name: string
```

However, when I send the field consisting of 1 character, it didn't throw me the error. Can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Regarding your [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54850216/what-is-the-equivalent-of-regex-for-new-regexp), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27626017/switching-from-regex-literals-to-regexp-constructor

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks man! It got one hell of a downvotes so I thought I asked a stupid question and deleted it.

Comment: You just need to understand what regex escape is. It seems you may use `RegExp('^(([^<>()[\\].,;:\\s@"]+(\\.[^<>()[\\].,;:\\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@(([^<>()[\\].,;:\\s@"]+\\.)+[^<>()[\\].,;:\\s@"]{2,})$', 'i')`. Note the single quotes around the string literal (no need to single-escape double quotes) and double backslashes where single ones were. I removed unnecessary escapes (`.` and `[` inside character classes are literal chars, no special ones).

Comment: Wow!!! Thank you so so so much man.

Comment: I will undelete the question. It would be awesome if you post this answer there. Maybe it would be helpful to some people. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54850216/what-is-the-equivalent-of-regex-for-new-regexp

Comment: No need to undelete that one I think. I just wanted to make sure you understand the problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Yeah, I understood it. Actually I was also including the regex cases inside of new RegExp so I got frustrated. Turns out `RegExp` supports another parameter where you include it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loopback 4 (as well as Loopback 3) does not support min/max properties by default and would not use it for validation of the data you send to the API. You can see the list of [supported property properties in the documentation for Loopback 3](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html#properties) as nothing has changed in Loopback 4.

Below is a statement from [the Loopback 4 documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Parsing-requests.html#request-body):

> The data from request body is validated against its OpenAPI schema specification. We use AJV module to perform the validation, which validates data with a JSON schema generated from the OpenAPI schema specification.

From [Open API V3 documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/data-types/#string) we can see they support `string` data type and

> String length can be restricted using minLength and maxLength:

[AJV support minLength and maxLength properties too](https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv/blob/master/KEYWORDS.md#keywords-for-strings), but for some reason, Loopback 4 does not have an easy, builtin way to define these properties with the @property decorator yet.

Anyway, I found a workaround which you can use for now:

```
import { Entity, model, property, Model } from '@loopback/repository';
import { getJsonSchema } from '@loopback/repository-json-schema';

@model()
export class MyModel extends Model {
  @property({
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
  })
  name: string;

  constructor(data?: Partial<MyModel>) {
    super(data);
  }

  static initialize() {
    let jsonSchema = getJsonSchema(MyModel) as any;
    jsonSchema.properties.name.minLength = 2;
    jsonSchema.properties.name.maxLength = 255;
  }
}

MyModel.initialize();
```

Note, all the magic happens in the `MyModel.initialize` method where I initialize `jsonSchema` using a standard `getJsonSchema` function (part of loopback). Then I extend this `jsonSchema` with additional `minLength` and `maxLength` properties. Inside of the `getJsonSchema` function they use a cache for json schemas, so the schema is generated just once for every model during the application lifecicle which ensures the values we set will stay there every time this json schema is requested later.

You can also see related issues on the Loopback Next's Github page:

- [Epic: Validation at Model/ORM level](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1872)
- [Complex OpenAPI Validations with `@property`](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1624)

Hopefully, they will support these types of validations as well as custom validators natively in Loopback decorators at some point.

Comment: Thanks man! You are a life savior. Just one question: How do you actually modify error messages in Loopback like `"{errors:{"email":["Field is invalid"]}"}`. Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54832216/how-to-modify-error-messages-in-loopback-4

Answer (score 3):

It should be like below,

```
@property({
   type: 'string',
   required: true,
   jsonSchema: {
      maxLength: 30,
      minLength: 10,
   },
})
name: string
```

You can refer the doc [here](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Parsing-requests.html)